# Thinkpad X1 Yoga OLED brightness

Tags: gnome, brightness, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 with GNOME (Wayland) on a Lenovo X1 Yoga OLED.

I believe this particular Ubuntu installation started out with Ubuntu 16.04 several years ago. I have been running GNOME on the system since it was first installed. - This means that I might have some ancient override left in my system that I have simply forgotten about.

The problem: I get a lot of error messages from gnome-settings-daemon in my journal:

```
feb 23 13:04:32 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:32 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
feb 23 13:04:33 kul pkexec[408567]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 843]
feb 23 13:04:33 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:33 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
feb 23 13:04:33 kul pkexec[408571]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 843]
feb 23 13:04:33 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:33 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
feb 23 13:04:34 kul pkexec[408575]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 758]
feb 23 13:04:34 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:34 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
feb 23 13:04:35 kul pkexec[408579]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 783]
feb 23 13:04:35 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:35 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
feb 23 13:04:35 kul pkexec[408585]: gdm: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/var/lib/gdm3] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness 800]
feb 23 13:04:35 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
feb 23 13:04:35 kul org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.desktop[1741]: This incident has been reported.
```

I have disabled/enabled "Automatic brightness" control in the Settings panel, it does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Observed similar in Ubuntu 18.04 (xorg based). Using `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled false` solved it by switching off automatic brightness.